# Upload/download data using Apple hosted content in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, download, upload, in-app-purchase, user-data

I am developing an app with Non-Consumable in-app purchase, and using Apple content hosting. But I don't have an imaging about upload/download data with Apple hosted content.
I have configured in-app purchase hosted content package, and uploaded to Apple store.

This is my code for restore function.

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restorePuchased {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

I want to upload/download user's data like: name, date of birth, city,... for restore in case delete and reinstall.

In the in-app purchase hosted package has the "ContentInfo.plist" file, but it just stores ContentVersion and IAPProductIdentifier. Can it store user's data like name, date of birth, etc,...? And how to upload/download this package to Apple hosted content server?

I have added parameters (UserInfo, UserWeight, UserHealthIndicators) like the image
[image]

Can I upload/download these parameters using "objectforkey" like

```
NSString *pathToYourContent = @""; // Path of file
NSString *contentInfoPath = [pathToYourContent 
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ContentInfo.plist"];
NSDictionary *contentInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:contentInfoPath];

NSString *userInfo = [contentInfo objectForKey:@"UserInfo"];
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can not store customize data for store hosted in Apple server. You can only store the data in your own server and map it with mapping the `original_transaction_id` from Apple in app purchase [receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html).

Comment: I have edited the question, please check again. Thank you.